# Error 1005 when Forward Engineering EER diagram

Tags: mysql, foreign-key, mysql-workbench, errors, database-diagrams

I have created an EER diagram (as shown in the image bellow) in MySQL Workbench  and wanted to Forward Engineer to build the DB.

[image: EER Diagram]

After configuring the model options to the Target MySQL Version and removing the word "Visible" from all the Indexes in the SQL Code (the code goes in the bottom of this post), as it was triggering an error, I have came across a 1005 Error:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table `books`.`books` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `books`.`books`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`books` (
          `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
          `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
          `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
          `book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
          `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`),
          INDEX `fk_books_book_prices1_idx` (`book_prices_book_priceID` ASC),
          INDEX `fk_books_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
          CONSTRAINT `fk_books_book_prices1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`book_prices_book_priceID`)
            REFERENCES `books`.`book_prices` (`book_priceID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
          CONSTRAINT `fk_books_transactions1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
            REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 8 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

Any guidance on how to solve it is appreciated.

---

The SQL Code that I am using is the following:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema books
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema books
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `books` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 ;
USE `books` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`book_prices`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_prices` (
  `book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `bookID` INT(11) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `currency` CHAR(2) NULL,
  `date_start` DATETIME NULL,
  `date_end` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_priceID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`transaction_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`transaction_types` (
  `transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transaction_typeID`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`transactions`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`transactions` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_transactions_transaction_types1_idx` (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_transactions_transaction_types1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transaction_types` (`transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`books`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`books` (
  `bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `ISBN` VARCHAR(13) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bookID`),
  INDEX `fk_books_book_prices1_idx` (`book_prices_book_priceID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_books_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_book_prices1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`book_prices_book_priceID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`book_prices` (`book_priceID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`batch_transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`batch_transaction` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_batch_transaction_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_batch_transaction_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`batches`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`batches` (
  `batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batch_transaction_transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `price` DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
  `supplierID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`batchID`),
  INDEX `fk_batches_batch_transaction1_idx` (`batch_transaction_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_batches_batch_transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batch_transaction_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batch_transaction` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`book_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`book_types` (
  `book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`book_typeID`),
  INDEX `fk_product_types_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_product_types_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_books1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_book_types_batches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`suppliers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`suppliers` (
  `supplierID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `batches_batchID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`supplierID`),
  INDEX `fk_suppliers_batches1_idx` (`batches_batchID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_suppliers_batches1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`batches_batchID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`batches` (`batchID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`customer_transaction`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`customer_transaction` (
  `transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `customerID` INT(11) NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`transactionID`),
  INDEX `fk_client_transaction_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_transaction_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`customers`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`customers` (
  `customerID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `books_bookID` INT(11) NULL,
  `books_book_prices_book_priceID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `books_book_types_book_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `customer_transaction_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`customerID`),
  INDEX `fk_clients_products1_idx` (`books_bookID` ASC, `books_book_prices_book_priceID` ASC, `books_book_types_book_typeID` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_clients_client_transaction1_idx` (`customer_transaction_transactionID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customrs_products1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`books_bookID` , `books_book_prices_book_priceID` , `books_book_types_book_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`books` (`bookID` , `book_prices_book_priceID` , `book_types_book_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_customers_customer_transaction1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`customer_transaction_transactionID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`customer_transaction` (`transactionID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`discounts`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`discounts` (
  `discountID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discountID`),
  INDEX `fk_discounts_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_discounts_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`discount_types`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`discount_types` (
  `discount_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Type` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `discounts_discountID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`discount_typeID`),
  INDEX `fk_discount_types_discounts1_idx` (`discounts_discountID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_discount_types_discounts1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`discounts_discountID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`discounts` (`discountID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `books`.`storagedistribution`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books`.`storagedistribution` (
  `storagedistributionID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `transactions_transactionID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` INT(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`storagedistributionID`),
  INDEX `fk_storagedistribution_transactions1_idx` (`transactions_transactionID` ASC, `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_storagedistribution_transactions1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`transactions_transactionID` , `transactions_transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    REFERENCES `books`.`transactions` (`transactionID` , `transaction_types_transaction_typeID`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved by updating the relationships in the diagram.

The first diagram was denormalized, which isn't necessarily bad if there are justifications for it (the consistency was enforced by the FK constraint).

I ended up referencing only the PK of the "parent" table, being the `_types` table a parent one.

Final diagram:

[image: Final EER Diagram]

Answer (score 3):

Error 150:

Plan A:  Rearrange the order of `CREATE TABLEs`

Plan B:  Disable FKs, create the tables, enable FKs.

Plan C:  Create the tables without FKs, then add `ALTERs` to add the FKs.